# Error: Incorrect syntax near '<'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Games] ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Games] (
    [GameID]
  , [Name]
  , [Description]
  , [Category]
  , [Price]
  , [ImageData]
  , [ImageMimeType]
) VALUES (
    1
    , N'SimCity'
    , N'Градостроительный симулятор снова с вами! Создайте город своей мечты'
    , N'Симулятор'
    , CAST(1999.00 AS Decimal(16, 2))
    , <SQLVARIANT>
    , NULL
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Games] OFF
```

Скрипт предлагается самой БД для заполнения, однако если пытаться его запустить вылезает данная ошибка. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

В столбец ImageData  ничего не передаете.
Добавил нулл.
Визуальных ошибок больше нет.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Games] 
([GameID], [Name], [Description], [Category], [Price], [ImageData], [ImageMimeType])
 VALUES (1, N'SimCity', N'Градостроительный симулятор снова с вами! Создайте город своей мечты', N'Симулятор', CAST(1999.00 AS Decimal(16, 2)),Null , NULL)
```

**UPD**
**SQLVARIANT** на это ругается, что предполагается передавать

Comment: Спасибо большое!)